# Multiple sets of jQuery for each image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML document with multiple image sliders that use HTML, CSS, and jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="slides-container">
  <img src="strbd-1.png" class='slides-placeholder'>
  <div class='slides-main'>
    <img src="strbd-1.png">
  </div>
  <div class='slides-main'>
    <img src="strbd-2.png">
  </div>
  <div class='slides-main'>
    <img src="strbd-3.png">
  </div>
  <div class='slides-main'>
    <img src="strbd-4.png">
  </div>
  <div class='slides-back slides-nav' onclick='plusDivs(-1)'>
    <span>&lt;</span>
  </div>
  <div class='slides-next slides-nav' onclick='plusDivs(1)'>
    <span>&gt;</span>
  </div>
  <div class='slides-menu'>
    <div class='slides-menu-inner'>
      <div class='slides-picker-outer'>
        <img class="slides-picker" src="strbd-1.png" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
      </div>
      <div class='slides-picker-outer'>
        <img class="slides-picker" src="strbd-2.png" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
      </div>
      <div class='slides-picker-outer'>
        <img class="slides-picker" src="strbd-3.png" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
      </div>
      <div class='slides-picker-outer'>
        <img class="slides-picker" src="strbd-4.png" onclick="currentDiv(4)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var menuleft = 0;
    var x = $(".slides-main");
    var i;
    var menu = $(".slides-menu");
    var dots = $(".slides-picker-outer");
    x.hide();
    dots.css("opacity","0.2");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x.eq(i).fadeOut(200);
    }
    x.eq(slideIndex-1).fadeIn(200);
    dots.eq(slideIndex-1).css("opacity","1.0");
    menuleft = dots.eq(slideIndex-1).position().left;
    menu.animate({scrollLeft: menuleft},200);
}
```

This works flawlessly when there is one image slider, but I have multiple on one page, and what ends up happening is that all of the slider controls control just the first one and the rest of the sliders just don't work.

How do I make it so that each image slider gets its own set of the JavaScript instead of all conflicting with each other?

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery and didn't find anything after searching online. I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:

*JSBin* - https://jsbin.com/yopoyedaze/edit?html,css,js,output

Only one slider works at a time and they scroll as if they were one big slider rather than two separate ones. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) looking like what you have? -- Please use [placeholder images](https://placeholder.com/) if you can't provide worikng URLs. --- At least reproduce the issue in a "sandbox" is a step...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes, added an edit

Comment: interesting....

Comment: You'll need to let the function take another argument for the slider's name. Maybe use an ID or a unique class for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yopoyedaze/edit?html,css,js,output), what I changed is pretty subtile.

I removed the useless `plusDivs(n)` and `currentDiv(n)` functions.
The addition to `slideIndex` is now made within `showDivs(n,el)`.

Now, you notice there is a second argument to the function.
That is to carry the element which triggers it.
This is a reference used to know which slider is involved by user action.

Starting from this element passed, we find the closest `.slides-container`...
And then, we can find the relevant children elements needed in the function.

**So passing a reference element is the big trick**.
This was your main issue.

```
var slideIndex = 1;

function showDivs(n,el) {

  // Get the right container from the passed element.
  var container = el.closest(".slides-container");

  // Find the child elements.
  var x = container.find(".slides-main");
  var menu = container.find(".slides-menu");
  var dots = container.find(".slides-picker-outer");

  var menuleft = 0;
  var i;

  // Calculate the new slideIndex.
  slideIndex += n;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (slideIndex < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}

  // Animate.
  x.hide();
  dots.css("opacity",0.2);
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x.eq(i).fadeOut(200);
  }
  x.eq(slideIndex-1).fadeIn(200);
  dots.eq(slideIndex-1).css("opacity",1);
  menuleft = dots.eq(slideIndex-1).position().left;
  menu.animate({scrollLeft: menuleft},200);
}

// Click handlers
$(".slides-next").on("click",function(){
  showDivs(1,$(this));
});
$(".slides-back").on("click",function(){
  showDivs(-1,$(this));
});
$(".slides-picker-outer").on("click",function(){
  showDivs($(this).index()+1-slideIndex,$(this));
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qjjrvo)

**I left you some work to do...**
The `slideIndex` is common to all sliders.
And this isn't really good.

I suggest you store this value in a data attribute on the container.
Something like `<div class="slides-container" data-slideIndex="1">`...

You can retreive this using `container.data("slideIndex")` and set it with `container.data("slideIndex",newSlideIndex)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it / but not with your slider. Conceptually - this should get you on the right track. This is just one way of thinking about this. You want each slider to have its own events and closure.

```js
var $box = $('.box');

function toggleBox(boxClass) { // some example 'plugin-like' function
  $(boxClass).on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
}

toggleBox('.one');

toggleBox('.two');

toggleBox('.three');
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.box.active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box one">box 1</div>

<div class="box two">box 2</div>

<div class="box three">box 3</div>
```

With that in mind, you can read something like this to make the 'plugin' style method more elegant. https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

### Plugin type of angle

```
(function($, sliderId) { // closure for this 'plugin'

    //   name of plugin - used as a method on a DOM element
    $.fn.initializeSlider = function(options) { // doesnt have options setup... but just to show where they would go

    return this.each( function() { // runs a function for each slider - which creates seperate places for all the stuff memory - for each slider in this case
      sliderId++; // something to increment so you can name each slider for example

      var sliderName = 'Slider-' + sliderId; // just for fun

      var $this = $(this); // cache the DOM element/node of 'this' slider so we don't have to keep querying for it... 

      // cache these nodes
      $prev = $this.find('.previous');
      $next = $this.find('.next');

      // whatever your methods are for a slider
      $prev.on('click', function() {
        console.log('Slide to previous for ' + sliderName);
      });

      $next.on('click', function() {
        console.log('Slide to next for ' + sliderName);
      });

      // just showing that multiple instances of this slider are initialized
      console.log('You created slider #' + sliderId);
    });

  }

})(jQuery, 0); // these things at the end are arguments 'passed' in to the larger function... it can feel strange... but it's just like any other function
// ourWholeFunction(jQuery, 0); 
// think about it like this ^ ... - they take the place of the parameters inside the function.

$('.slider').initializeSlider();
```

Here is that in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ecw95of3/

Check out this repo for a good example: https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/blob/master/responsiveslides.js  - however, jQuery plugins should have a destroy method and this one doesn't.

I general... besides learning about JavaScript... you should leave *Sliders* to the pros. Just use https://flickity.metafizzy.co/

Good luck!

Comment: *«This is how you would do it / but not with your slider.»* - How can this be an answer?

Comment: "How do I make it so that each FILL IN THE BLANK gets its own set of the JavaScript instead of all conflicting with each other?" Is how I read it.

Comment: My reading is that your answer isn't clear. But I may be stupid. Being the OP, I would ask ... things...

Comment: It says on your website that you know 100% of jQuery, so you are definitely not stupid. These questions are not supposed to be - :*my code is broken... help*" / so I thought that a tiny example would be better to learn from. You should answer it too. : )

Comment: I try to help.. With efforts sometimes. Is that a challenge? Is it appropriate?

Comment: Haha. Friendly learning experience. I'm trying to think of a cleaner way to explain it too.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm still not sure how your example would scale up to my slider - I have multiple functions that are called with parameters from HTML elements, how do I make sure they use the right variables and the right set of slides are being selected? Can you give me a more specific example?

Comment: @wwsalmon - take a look at my additions. Hopefully the comments explain it well. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek Thanks for the edit! I rebuilt my slider code as a plugin, but now instead of cycling through all sliders as one the first slider controls the second one and doesn't work: https://jsbin.com/dajefabaza/edit?html,css,js,output Can you help me figure out why?

Comment: First off - this is a great example of why you should not put your actions IN the markup.`onclick='plusDivs(-1)` is no bueno. They could be wrong etc. What if you had 20 sliders? They need to be in the actual plugin. You've got the idea. I believe in you. `buttonClick` is a pretty terrible function name. Simplify things until you find the reason. Here are some thoughts on simplified markup: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/5740b6374f9c3049fb6e01b2dc62edc6?editors=1010  I believe in you! Good Luck!

Comment: @sheriffderek The inline onclicks actually don't do anything after I changed the JS, I just forgot to update the markup. You've been really helpful so far, but I've been trying all day and can't figure out why the code doesn't work, it looks fine in theory. I'm new to jQuery, and figure there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding. I would really appreciate if you could just give a direct answer as to why my code isn't working. Updated markup - https://jsbin.com/nafuxiwipa/edit?html,css,js,output